# Is the name Avner ben Ner "backwards"?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Avner means "the father of Ner", but Avner's actual father was named just "Ner"!

Shouldn't Avner's father have been called "Avner", and the son have been called "Ner"?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very simple answer to your question. Avner had a son, who he named Ner to respect his father, Ner.

Comment: :-& Duhhhhh .... WHy didn't I think of that???

Answer (score 3):

Much as [Our Lord and Savior Zaphod Beeblebrox](/q/55237)'s father was Zaphod Beeblebrox the Second, Avner's father was Ner. Presumably in honor of Our Lord.