# Avner ben Ner: significance of "Ner" in both parts of his name?

Tags: names, symbols-symbology

King Saul had a general named Avner ben Ner.

The "ner" in his first name is very similar to his last name.

His name thus means father of light/son of light.

Is there any commentary/explanation/backstory regarding this?

My thought is that there is a kind of Janus symbology at play. His past (father) and future (son) is illuminated, but not his present. But this explanation doesn't fit the character.

There is a closed Purim Torah question that references this.

[Is the name Avner ben Ner "backwards"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55883/is-the-name-avner-ben-ner-backwards)

Comment: His father's name was Ner, and his father named his son to point out that fact. Avner means "[his] father is Ner" I'm not sure I understand your question

Comment: Just adding to @robev's comment, the very first time Avner appears in Tanach, in Shmuel 1:14:50, he is called "Aviner" - "my father is Ner".

Comment: @Harel no, aviner means father of ner. Avi with a kamatz is my father. Avi with chataf patach is in smichut like וְחָם הוּא אֲבִי כְנָעַן or אֲבִי כָּל-תֹּפֵשׂ כִּנּוֹר וְעוּגָב

Comment: @DoubleAA good to know, thanks.